# Loading external libraries in a SharePoint WebPart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am working with SharePoint Framework and building a custom WebPart for SharePoint Online. Following the [instructions here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195570/sharepoint-framework-loading-font-awesome-css-from-cdn), I can't get any libraries loaded from external CDNs.

This is the error I get every time: **The entry point for component "my-component-id-here" (SalesNavigationWebPart) has a dependency on "@microsoft/sp-loader" that is not declared in the manifest.**

[image: SPFx Error loading external libraries]

I tried to load it by adding an entry to *externals: {}* in *config.json*, but the error is still there. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I uploaded the .sppkg without importing the sp-loader (in code) first time. Next time even if you add the sp-loaded and deploy the cdn files it won't work. 
you need to use below commands and redeploy .sppkg file in app catalog.

```
gulp clean
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship
```

Further reading,
While you execute the gulp bundle --ship command inside the temp/deploy folder there will be a .json file with the GUID of your web part. It has the reference to the sp-loader module.